# Maven command line options from profile

Tags: maven

In my CI pipeline I am running commands like these, all with the same options:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="\
  -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn \
  --batch-mode \
  --activate-profiles pipelines \
"
mvn verify
```

The first two options are just to make Maven less verbose, the last one is setting a custom profile that is defined in pom.xml.

Is it possible to somehow define options (like the first two here) in the Maven profile and just run maven with only the profile option?

```
mvn verify --activate-profiles pipelines  # all options defined in profile
```

Comment: First if you are using Maven 3.6.1+ you can simply use `--no-transfer-progress` to reduce the output.. Second why do you need for every build a profile? Usually you should get your build running without a profile. What kind of CI solution do you use?

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise. Batch mode sounds safer than just less verbose interactive mode on CI, doesn't it? Or is the option the equivalent of the slf4j setting? The profile is used to upload artefacts to a different repository, to exclude some local dev tools etc. When developing locally, I use the default profile.

Comment: The `--batch-mode` turns off color on console and yes interactive mode (which is usually not a problem; except you would have to input something). The `--no-transfer-progress`  is the equivalent of the slf4j settings... Using different repositories? Are you using a repository manager?